# Persistent Internal Server Error (Django & Ajax)

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I am using Ajax to transfer my data to views.py. I already terminated all my urls and used the form action for my url but the internal server error still persists. I can't seem to find the problem pls help

**HTML**

```
<form action = "{% url 'create_user' %}" id="create_user" method="post">

    {%  csrf_token %}
    <p class="label" id="l1"> Name: </p>
    <input type="text" class="textbox" id="name"><br>

    <p class="label" id="l2"> Username: </p>
    <input type="text" class="textbox" id="username"><br>

    <p class="label" id="l3"> Password: </p>
    <input type="password" class="textbox" id="password"><br>

    <p class="label" id="l4"> Confirm Password: </p>
    <input type="password" class="textbox" id="confirm"><br>

    <button id="signupbutton">Sign Up</button>

    <div id="separator"></div>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
 $("#signupbutton").click(function () {
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var confirm = $("#confirm").val();
        var name = $("#name").val();

        errorval = errorCheck();
        if (errorval == 0) {
            // transform data input to dictionary
            var infoset = {
                "name": name,
                "username": username,
                "password": password
            };
            console.log(infoset);

            var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');

            $.ajaxSetup({
                beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
                    if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
                        xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
                    }
                }
            });
            var url = $('#create_user').attr('action');
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "POST",
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: {
                    "name": name,
                    "username": username,
                    "password": password
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                fail: function (data) {
                    console.log("everything went to shit");
                }

            });

            $("#errormsg").text('creation successful');
```

I didn't use infoset because I felt like it was being a cause of the problem? So I tried manually putting the data in the ajax

**views.py**

```
def create_user(request) -> HttpResponse:
if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST.get('username', None)
    if username is None:
        return HttpResponse(status=400)

    username = request.POST.get('username')
    password = request.POST.get('password')
    response_data = {}

    user = User(username, password)
    user.save()

    response_data['result'] = 'Create post successful!'
    response_data['userpk'] = user.pk
    response_data['username'] = user.username

    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps(response_data),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
else:
    return HttpResponse(
        json.dumps({"nothing to see": "this isn't happening"}),
        content_type="application/json"
    )
```

I tried narrowing down the cause of the error so when I did the 404 error checking, it fired. There was nothing in my username data and I don't know whats causing it.

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls, name="admin"),
    url(r'^$', views.home, ),
    url(r'^home/$', views.home, name="home"),
    url(r'^sign_up/$', views.sign_up, name="sign_up"),
    url(r'^marketplace/$', views.marketplace, name="marketplace"),
    url(r'^create_user/$', views.create_user, name="create_user"),

]
```

Comment: I think I imported User from django.contrib.auth.models in views.py

Comment: can you do a dump on `user` and see if it contains actual values you need.. also just add a `try - catch` block to your `create user` method

Comment: You said you're getting an internal server error so there should be an exception in the server logs. What does it say?

Comment: I found the problem apparently my form with method post is conflicting with my ajax and my data needed to be passed with the JSON.stringify function. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
data: {
    "name": name,
    "username": username,
    "password": password
},
```

Try to use

`data: $("#your-form-id").serialize()`

regards

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys apparently my form method=post was conflicting with my jquery and the only thing that was wrong was I forgot to JSON.stringify my data then parse it in the controller